# Django file not uploaded using FileField(upload to=) from admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have a problem that is i can't upload files from admin panel to my folder `document` in media , i try to upload but it always failed the server still uploading and the end it say error 500 request time out , so after i tried many solution i thing my problem with mysql db or with django

my Django version 3.0.3 and python 3.7 and i am using namecheap shared hosting

settings.py :

```
# media dir
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join('/home/traixmua/public_html/media')
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...  
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

handler404 = 'blog_app.views.handler404'
```

models.py :

```
class Trainer(models.Model):
    .....
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

- note : when i try to upload files using SQLite on local server not in hosting it's work good but with mysql i have this problem , i can choose the file but it won't to upload

the error is :

[image]

Comment: What is this well? You asked same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75686268/17562044) 2 hours ago, and you again ask it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i can't upload files from django admin panel and just still loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75686268/i-cant-upload-files-from-django-admin-panel-and-just-still-loading)

Comment: sorry about that but i forget to give more info about problem and i delete last questions and i provide more info here

Comment: Ok I understand but from next time always edit the question if you want to share more details.

Comment: The issue can be with either size of the file or file permissions of the media directory on the server.

Comment: the file size under 1mb so i don't think the problem from the size , and how to fix this problem if it from server

Comment: Did you already set some `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE`?

Comment: mm no i don't , where to add this code ?

Comment: Try to set `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 10485760` in `settings.py`, its mean 10 mb files can he uploaded, currently it is in bytes, then check.

Comment: Ok i will and tell you thanks for your time

Comment: that's not working too , nothing happened just uploading and error request time out